# Mouse cursor on vps win server 2012 R2 not working

Tags: hyper-v, remote-desktop, remote-access, windows-server-2012-r2

i have server with hyper-v manager on network (Windows server 2012).
But after installing i can't click nowhere, the keyboard works but the mouse is not.

**Google did not tell me anything.**

The mouse cursor looks like dot, not a classic mouse cursor.
I have many vps servers, on win server 2008, or 2012, but problem is only with 2012 R2.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8dSi.png

thank you for answering.

Comment: I don't understand. Is this a virtual machine or a physical machine? If this is a virtual machine then what virtualization platform is it running on? If this is a virtual machine have you installed the virtual machine tools or integration services?

Comment: Hello. I have one physical server. I'm on it via remote desktop. And there i have the Hyper-V VPS with Windows Server 2012 R2. I can not get in the order of remote desktop-hyper-v console. On this vps over remote desktop-hyper-v console is not mouse cursor, but dot cursor withou click option and other.

Comment: I still don't understand. Is the machine that has the "dot" mouse cursor a physical machine or a virtual machine?

Comment: Has no cursor on the virtual machine.

Comment: OK, still not directly answering my question but I'll surmise that the problem machine is a virtual machine hosted on Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012. Have you installed the Hyper-V Integration Services in the virtual machine? If not, then you need to and that will probably resolve the problem. Also, in Hyper-V Manager go to Hyper-V Settings, go to the "Reset Check Boxes" settings and click the Reset button. Then click the mouse inside of the virtual machine console/window and tell me if you get any message.

Comment: I have installed integration services. You mean this ? http://d.pr/i/FfSn, after reset button. This is message http://d.pr/i/TIZL I do not understand :(

Comment: because i can't install integration services to vm. :( mouse not working.

Comment: Sure you can. You don't need the mouse for that. Open the Virtual Machine Connection window for the VM, select "Action... Insert Integration Services Setup Disk" and use the keyboard to tab to the buttons, etc. that you need to run the installation. Once the Integration Services are installed you should be able to use the mouse.

Comment: ok, after install and reboot i have this message. http://d.pr/i/49fO mouse stil does't work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the same issue I just had:

I downloaded the VMs from Microsoft to let me test IE. They were Virtual PC images which I used as HyperV disks, creating a new Virtual Machine for them.

After booting, my mouse cursor was a small dot (not a cursor I'm familiar with), and clicking didn't seem to do anything. The keyboard worked.

After getting to desktop, I could click - the mouse pointer was not movable on the guest, but I could toggle desktop items (because Win7 has that 'show desktop' button in the bottom-right corner). So clicking worked but the pointer was trapped.

The fix was to go to Programs and Features (using the keyboard) and uninstall the VM guest additions (in this case they were VirtualPC additions that didn't completely work with Hyper-V).

After uninstalling them, mount the Integration Services Pack DVD (Hyper-V Action menu) and it will let you install it. After a reboot the mouse is working again.